# Sampling by Group in R with no replacement but the final result cannot contain any repeats as well

Tags: r, dplyr, sampling

I am trying to construct a control group. ID_1 is the original participant, ID_2 is the control. For simplicity sake they are matched by sex and age. I received a dataframe that  looks like this:

```
ID_1 <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4)
Sex <- c("M","M","M","F","F","M","M","F","F","F")
Age <- c(23,23,23,35,35,44,44,35,35,35)
ID_2 <- c(321,322,323,630,631,502,503,630,631,632)

df <- data.frame(ID_1, Sex, Age, ID_2)
```

So I have several matches for each ID_1 and I want to sample within each group to get just one. I got that with:

```
library(dplyr)

random_ID_2 <- df %>% group_by(ID_1) %>% sample_n(size = 1, replace = F)
```

The problem is that I do not want to get any repeats of ID_2. So by random chance I could  end up pairing ID_1 = 2 and ID_1 = 4 to the same control ID_2 = 630

How i can make sure this does not happen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps, add a `distinct` in between i.e. `df %>% distinct(ID_1, ID_2, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%  group_by(ID_1) %>% sample_n(size = 1, replace = FALSE)`

Comment: Hey akrun! I tried on the real data and it gave me a similar result to my simple code with  ~850 repeats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use a `data.table` solution:

```
dt <- setnames(
        unique(
          setorder(
            setDT(copy(df))[, idx := 1:.N, by = ID_1], # add an index column for each ID_1 group
            idx, ID_1)                                 # sort by idx, ID_1
          # for each Sex/Age group, sample unique values of ID_2 withouth replacement (pad with NA)
          [, ID_3 := c(sample(unique(ID_2)), rep(NA, .N - uniqueN(ID_2))), by = c("Sex", "Age")],
          by = "ID_1") # get the first row for each ID_1 group
        [, c(1:3, 6)], "ID_3", "ID_2") # remove helper columns and rename "ID_3" to "ID_2"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help jblood94. I tested this on the real data and it seems to give me solid results, with no repeats in the end vector. 

I included an extra variable in the c("Age", "Sex") part of the code (more vars in the real data), fiddle a little with the deleted columns. That was expected....I also had to use skip_absent = TRUE in order for it to work which was a minor surprise and took me a bit to figure out.

PS - I cant vote because I don't have enough reputation

Comment: Glad to hear it. Even if you can't upvote, you should be able to accept the answer if it ended up working out for you.

Comment: Indeed, I just did that!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one potential option that samples and if there is a duplicate it will resample:

```
# handles case where no samples left
my_sample <- function(x, ...){
  if (length(x) == 0L) return(NA) else sample(x, ...)
}

df %>% 
  group_by(ID_1) %>% 
  slice_sample(n = 1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(resample = duplicated(ID_2)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(ID_2 = if (resample) my_sample(df[df$ID_1 == ID_1 & df$ID_2 != ID_2, "ID_2"], 1) else ID_2) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-resample)
```

One thing to note is that rows further down your data frame with duplicate `ID_2` are conditionally sampling.

**Output**

`set.seed(17)` is a case where the same `ID_2` is sampled:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID_1) %>% 
  slice_sample(n = 1)

  ID_1 Sex     Age  ID_2
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 M        23   322
2     2 F        35   631
3     3 M        44   502
4     4 F        35   631
```

And to test the above code:

```
set.seed(17)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID_1) %>% 
  slice_sample(n = 1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(resample = duplicated(ID_2)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(ID_2 = if (resample) my_sample(df[df$ID_1 == ID_1 & df$ID_2 != ID_2, "ID_2"], 1) else ID_2) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-resample)

   ID_1 Sex     Age  ID_2
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 M        23   322
2     2 F        35   631
3     3 M        44   502
4     4 F        35   632
>
```

Again to emphasize my point above `ID_1 == 4` is conditionally sampling since we allow `ID_1 == 2` to remain matched to `ID_2 == 631` and change the match for `ID_1 == 4`.

**How it works**

1. Sample your data as you normally would.
2. Then we we check for duplicates in `ID_2`. Note: `duplicated` returns `TRUE` for all *subsequent* duplicated IDs.
3. If a row needs to be resampled then we subset and sample from the original data frame with the line `mutate(ID_2 = if ...)`

Comment: Thank you LMc! You definitely got the right idea. I will test your solution on the real data soon but looking at your code I have one question: What happens if I ran out of options for ID_2?  As in: all my resampling will bring repeated values because there is no value in that group that was not used before.....Will I enter into an infinite loop?

Comment: @George Great point. No you won't get stuck in an infinite loop. `sample` will throw an error. I added a wrapper function to handle this type of case. Use `my_sample` instead, it will return `NA` if there are no more IDs to sample.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer LMc! As soon as I can test the solution I will give feedback here.

Comment: So I tested the code in the real data (almost 3 million rows which means on average about a 100 ID_2 for each ID_1) --> I have ~30k ID_1's

Results were good but not perfect. in about 150 instances I am still getting repeats. I don't know Why.  Number of NAs never change and is around 60.

I selected the repeated values and could not see a pattern to it.

Comment: Changing the code to include sex and age in group_by reduced the repeats by about half, but they still there....so there is that.

Comment: @George it's hard to debug the problem without a reproducible example. I don't see how duplication could be possible, but there could be something in your data unaccounted for in your example and my subsequent answer.

Comment: Yes, I understand LMc. Unfortunately I can't show a subset of the data here and R gives me no error messages that could shed a light into the problem. Thanks again! It did help me regardless. (I cant vote yet, so you know)